Typo3 new install V12 error "must be of type ?int, string given"
After installing V12.4, I get several errors when trying to create new content-elements, files or other elements. I installed Typo3 from the CLI with the command
composer create “typo3/cms-base-distribution:^12” . --prefer-dist

It is a fresh install on php8.2, Typ3 V12.4 gets installed. No plugins yet.
On the same server I have Typo3 V11 running without these problems. Both as a subdomain, so the configuration of the server is the same.
Basically the error is that core-files are hard-coded with declare(strict_types=1);. The error occure when arguments come from a query. var_dump() shows that all fields of the query are returned as string instead of the types in MySQL. In this case the uid is expected to be an int.
Any ideas?

Add this DB configuration to settings.php.
'DB' => [
    ...
    'driverOptions' => [
         17 => false, // OR PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false
         20 => false, // OR PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
     ]
 ]


Tried it, but no luck. Then I added these lines just before the error to check if the settings were picked-up:

$db = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
var_dump($db-> getConnectionByName('Default'));`

which gave me this information:

 ["params":"Doctrine\DBAL\Connection":private]=>`
  array(10) {
    ["charset"]=> string(7) "utf8mb4"
    ["driver"]=>  string(9) "pdo_mysql"
    ["host"]=>    string(9) "localhost"
    ...
    ["driverOptions"]=>
    array(2) {
      [17]=> bool(false)
      [20]=> bool(false)
    }
